# How to call two different create methods at single call in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and developing a small user application. In my app, I have a user model and a subscription model. I want that when a user creates his/her profile and hits the submit button , another action should be called at the same time known as subscription which enters the data of the user such as profile_id , subscription_id, plan_id and generates a raw state, in the same subscription table. I am using 'AASM' for state management. I know how to insert values in the subscription table using console, which works fine. But , I want to create new subscription as soon as the user registers his new profile. I mean , how shall I call two create methods at single event.

Comment: please provide some code so we can help you more and also, if you're new to rails i do suggest starting with rails 3 already as you'll eventually upgrade to 3 someday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get it clearly but i guess `after_create` is all you need.
(assuming `user :has_one => :profile`, and `profile has_many => :subscriptions`)

In `profile` model

```
after_create :subscribe!
```

`attr_accessor :plan_id, :subscription_id`

```
def subscribe!
  self.subscriptions << Subscription.new(:plan_id => plan_id, :subscription_id => subscription_id)
  self.save
end
```